# Converting panoramic MF lenses to 35mm equivalents?

Tags: lens, 35mm, medium-format

[This](https://shootitwithfilm.com/understanding-medium-format-vs-35mm-lenses/) random website I found talks about estimating the 35mm camera equivalent lens sizes for various MF frame sizes (645, 6x6, 6x7, 6x8 and 6x9).  But I am interested in shooting panoramic MF with 6x12 or 6x17 frame sizes.

That website says you divide the 35mm diagonal by the MF frame diagonal to get the "crop factor".  And then you multiply that crop factor by the MF lens size to get the 35mm equivalent.  But does that still hold true for MF panoramic frames?

EG for a 6x17 frame, the crop factor is about 0.24 (35mm has a 43mm diagonal, 6x17 has a 180mm diagonal), so a 105mm MF lens would be the equivalent of a 25mm lens on a 35mm camera.  Is this correct?

The basis for my question is trying to estimate the vertical size of a subject on a 6x17 frame for a given MF lens size, based on the image size of the same subject on my D7500 and DX kit lens at a given focus length.

Comment: Did you consider the image circle produced by the DSLR lens? Your image will likely show severe vignetting. And even if the image circle is wide enough, how is the distortion and color aberration beyond the 35mm image circle?

Comment: @xenoid I'm not using the DX lens on the MF camera.  I am trying to estimate what MF lens on the MF camera will achieve the same vertical height of the subject that I obtained with my D7500 and DX lens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite subjective what is considered "equivalent" when you are comparing formats that use different aspect ratios. I wouldn't bother with crop factors if I were doing this. If I wanted to visualise what I'd get shooting 6x12 or 6x17, I'd use [Rui Salgueiro's field-of-view calculator](https://www.mat.uc.pt/%7Erps/photos/angles.html) (or similar) to find out the actual **horizontal** angle of view for the MF lens on the 612/617 camera. Then I'd use the same calculator to find what focal length would give me the same horizontal AoV on my DX camera. Then I'd shoot some subject using the DX camera at that focal length, and post-crop the photo to the same aspect ratio that the MF camera produces.

Having said that, it seems I initially misinterpreted what you're trying to achieve here. If you stand somewhere and take a photo of, for example, a tree, using a 50mm focal length on your DX camera, in landscape orientation, and the tree exactly fills the frame from top to bottom, then you need to determine the **vertical** angle of view that your 50mm lens produces *on the DX format*. Find what focal length will produce the same vertical AoV on the 612/617 camera. Then, taking a photo from the same spot with the 612/617 camera, you'll again fill the frame, top to bottom, with the tree, but because of the much wider aspect ratio, you'll include much more of the scene either side of the tree.

Taking the Fujifilm GX617 just as an example, there were 4 lenses available: 90mm, 105mm, 180mm and 300mm. A 50mm focal length on your DX sensor takes in a vertical AoV of 17.8°. The 180mm GX617 lens appears to give the same – 17.7° – so this would be your equivalent lens in this case.

Comment: I'll definitely look into that calculator page, but your have my use case backwards.  From a set location, and set focal length I took a photo with my D7500.  I now want to determine if I can achieve the the same vertical height in the frame of the MF camera, using the known focal lengths available for the 6x17 camera (and from roughly the same location)

Comment: @PeterM So, you stand somewhere and take a photo of (e.g.) a tree, using a 25mm lens on your DX camera, in landscape orientation. And the tree fills the frame exactly top to bottom. Then you need to determine the **vertical** angle of view that your 25mm lens produces on the DX format. Find what focal length will produce the same vertical AoV on the 612/617 camera. Then, taking a photo from the same spot with the 612/617 camera, you'll again fill the frame, top to bottom, with the tree, but because of the much wider aspect ratio, you'll include much more of the scene either side of the tree

Comment: Can you explain the numbers from that calculator?   Are the "hor" and "vert" results meant to be in degrees?  If they are, then plugging in numbers for 35mm gives a "vert" of 26.6 for a 50mm focal length.  Then if I plug in 6x6 (as I only care about the vertical size) I get 31.3 for a focal length of 100mm.  So a 100mm lens on a 6x17 should have about the same vertical subject height as a 50mm lens on a 35mm camera.  Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, of course they are degrees - what else? You might consider 26.6 and 31.3 to be "about the same"; I don't. Entering 110mm focal length for the 6x6 format gets you much closer.

Comment: That site never explicitly says what the results are, and even has confusing information on the results with displaying the "length" and "width".  So without seeing the actual methodology used of course I'm going to question the results /s  Also, YMMV for "about".  But anyway, I didn't realize you could also edit the focal lengths, and I see that a MF 105 is closer to a 50mm on a 35mm camera.

Comment: A 50mm lens in the full-frame 135 format gives a vertical AoV of 27°. 105mm focal length on 6x6 gives 29.9°. The actual closest focal length on 6x6 is 117mm, which gives a vertical AoV of 26.9°. The Fujifilm GX617 had 4 lenses: 90, 105, 180 and 300. So if you were going to choose one of these, then yeah, 105 would be the closest. But also, you said you were using a DX camera. Are you actually using a 50mm focal length on the DX format, but here looking at angles for a 50mm lens on full-frame? 50mm on DX format gives vertical AoV of 17.8°

Comment: It's a DX lens on DX camera.  The EXIF data says "Focal Length: 50mm", but also has a line that says "Focal Length in 35mm film: 75mm", which seems correct for my camera.

Comment: Also the GX617 is probably out of my budget.  I might be able to manage a G617 which has a fixed 105mm lens.

Comment: "It's a DX lens on DX camera." Yes! It's a 50mm lens on a **smaller** sensor than full-frame. So it obviously encompasses a smaller angle of view than a 50mm focal length does on full-frame. A 50mm focal length on your DX sensor only takes in a vertical AoV of 17.8°. That's the whole point. So the "equivalent" lens (for the same vertical AoV) on 617 format is actually 180mm!

Comment: Shoot.  I assumed that for a given focal length the DX lens on a DX body, that it matched the full frame lens on a full frame body.  But I just checked.  My DX lens at 50mm on my DX camera has the same AoV as my normal lens at 75mm on my F100.  So yeah, now I need to be saving up for the GX617

Comment: Yes. 50mm is 50mm. The fact it's a DX lens doesn't change that - it only affects the size of the image circle.

Answer (score 1):

Crop factors based on the diagonal are approximate when used between frames with different aspect ratios.  If you are interested in vertical size you should do the same computation for the vertical sizes of your frames.  The standard 35mm in landscape mode is 24mm high.  Divide this by the vertical dimension of your 6x17 frame and you have the crop factor to use.  If the 6 is actual 6 cm height=60mm height, your crop factor is 24/60=0.4.  If your frame is somewhat smaller the crop factor will be somewhat larger.

Comment: Can you explain the workings of your estimation?  Because by your method, if I turn the 6x17 camera from landscape to portrait, then the crop factor changes.

Comment: @PeterM Then you would use 170mm instead of 60mm for the image height of the 6x17 camera. 36/170 is 0.21, assuming you also use the 35mm camera in portrait orientation. Since in this case the OP is comparing to a DX, rather than FF camera, the relative comparison in portrait orientation would be a crop factor of 0.21 for the 6x17 and a crop factor of 1.5 for the DX camera, so a combined  0.14 ratio between the two cameras.

Comment: Though I doubt that 6x12 is actually 60x120mm and that 6x17 is actually 60x170mm any more than 6x6 is actually 60x60mm (it's typically 56x56mm for most 6x6 cameras, though it can vary significantly from one manufacturer to the next).